# Room not retaining data in one table

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

My application works fine upon opening. It is able to prepopulate the database from a text file in the raw folder. When I open the fragment that displays the list of exercises, the query runs fine and one can see the whole list. If I press the back button to exit the app completely and then reenter, no problem, the list populates again. The problem is when I press the recents button and hit close all. When I reenter the application, the query for all of the exercises yields nothing and the list is empty. I have searched high and low and have found nothing. Attached is hopefully enough code to diagnose issue. The AppDatabase class is based off the Google Architecture BasicSample app.

```
@Database(entities = {BodySectionEntity.class, CardioEntity.class, ExerciseEntity.class, GoalEntity.class, SetRecordEntity.class, WorkoutEntity.class, WorkoutLibraryEntity.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({Converter.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static final String TAG = "AppDatabase";

private static AppDatabase sInstance;

@VisibleForTesting
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ig_db";

public abstract BodySectionDao bodySectionDao();
public abstract ExerciseDao exerciseDao();
public abstract WorkoutDao workoutDao();
public abstract SetRecordDao setRecordDao();

private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> mIsDatabaseCreated = new MutableLiveData<>();


public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getInstance()");
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = buildDatabase(context.getApplicationContext());
                sInstance.updateDatabaseCreated(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}

private static AppDatabase buildDatabase(final Context appContext) {
    Log.d(TAG, "build database");
    return Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
            .addCallback(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onCreate(db);
                    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext);
                                List<String> groups = Arrays.asList(appContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.groups));
                                populateDatabase(appContext, database, groups);
                                database.setDatabaseCreated();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onOpen(db);
                }
            }).build();
}

/**
 * Check whether the database already exists and expose it via {@link #getDatabaseCreated()}
 */
private void updateDatabaseCreated(final Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updatedatabasecreated");
    if (context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).exists()) {
        setDatabaseCreated();
    }
}

private void setDatabaseCreated(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setdatabasecreated");
    mIsDatabaseCreated.postValue(true);
}

public LiveData<Boolean> getDatabaseCreated() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getdatabasecreated");
    return mIsDatabaseCreated;
}

private static void populateDatabase(final Context context, final AppDatabase db, final List<String> groups) throws IOException {
    //insert the body parts
    Log.d(TAG, "populateDatabase");
    List<BodySectionEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String section : groups) {
        list.add(new BodySectionEntity(section));
    }
    db.bodySectionDao().insertAll(list);

    //insert the exercise data
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.exercise_data);
    List<ExerciseEntity> exerciseEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("IGv2", "inside while");
            String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, ",");
            exerciseEntities.add(new ExerciseEntity(
                    strings[0].trim(),
                    findBodySectionKey(strings[1], groups),
                    strings[2].trim(),
                    strings[3].trim(),
                    strings[4].trim(),
                    strings[5].trim()));
        }
        Log.i("IGv2", "size: " + exerciseEntities.size());
        db.exerciseDao().insertAll(exerciseEntities);
        Log.i("IGv2", "exercises entered");
    }
}

//grabs the correct id for the COL_BODY_SECTION_ID column and returns it
private static int findBodySectionKey(String part, final List<String> groups) {
    Log.d("IGv2", "findboydsectionkey");
    int index = groups.indexOf(part);
    return ++index;
}
}
```

ExerciseDao

```
@Dao
public interface ExerciseDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(List<ExerciseEntity> exercises);

@Query("Select * From exercise Order By body_section_id, exercise ASC")
LiveData<List<ExerciseEntity>> getAllExercises();
}
```

WorkoutFragment

```
…
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WorkoutViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getAllExercises().observe(this, new Observer<List<ExerciseEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<ExerciseEntity> exerciseEntities) {
            if (exerciseEntities != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Size: " + exerciseEntities.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mExerAdapter.setExerciseList(exerciseEntities);
            }
        }
    });
    mWorkoutAdapter.setWorkout(mViewModel.getWorkout());
}
```

If more is needed, please advise. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix to be in the creation of the AppDatabase where at the very bottom through `db.exerciseDao().insertAll(exerciseEntities);` I tried to do an insert with over 500 records. When I put a for statement around it and did each one individually, it worked with no issues. I found other sources online that said using a SQLite transaction works better for that large number of inserts at once and also that SQLite can only handle 500 inserts at once. Either way the for statement solved the issue